# How to view quickly spawned/killed processes on a Fedora Linux machine?

Tags: linux, process, htop, tracing

On Windows, there is a program available for download which is part of what's called the `sysinternals suite` of tools. This program is called Process Explorer 64 aka ProcExp64. The program is useful for amongst many other things, identifying potential malware on a machine because one common behavior of malware is to launch and kill processes essentially faster than the typical program and/or the human eye could perceive/notice. This posed a challenge using the Windows Task Manager, because a malware may quickly launch, launch a child process, inject into another process and then kill the child all in under 1 second, for example (potentially even under 200ms). ProcExp64 has what's called `Difference Highlight Duration` which highlights a killed process to a specified color and keeps it in the process list for some duration, even after it's killed. In fact, the user can even specify to "scroll to new process", which I simply use sort by `PID` for on linux in `htop`. I do see an `update time` setting in `htop` but if I make that larger, it may miss the launch altogether.

On Linux, I've found a similar issue and I'm not sure how to solve it. In this case, I am not trying to observe malware, but I am trying to observe other, non-malicious processes that begin and exit quickly. An example is that I noticed that when I enter the command `ps aux | grep ld-linux`, I get an output, but then when I view `htop`, there is no such process still running because I believe the `ld-linux` executable exits and remains present only in `shared object (.so)` space rather than as a separate process (I could be wrong, but this is how I understand what's happening). One reason I suspect this is the case is that every time I run the aforementioned command, the PID is incremented further and further for `ld-linux` because I think that is the instance that was loaded in the actual loading process for `ps` itself (again, just speculation). Is there a way to observe this in action using `htop` or some other tool to put some kind of delay on the existence of the `ld-linux` loader process in the process table/list, and otherwise highlight it so that it stands out?

Comment: I guess it could be done using `auditd`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the kernel tracing tools found at
[github](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc), or in a package called `bcc-tools`
or similar, depending on your system. It contains, for example, `execsnoop`
to trace `exec()` syscalls. It needs to be run as root, and your kernel
needs to have been compiled with the appropriate flags, which is usually the
case. See the [tutorial](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md).